# How long does it takes to receive a master graduation document (degree)

Tags: thesis, titles, graduation, defense

Can any body tell me how long after the Master's thesis defense do it take the student to receive their Master graduation document (degree) in Spain, France, UK or USA?

I'm asking specifically about the degree *in paper*, the one stamped with signatures, etc (which you can hang in the wall :) ).

For example if the student were to defend their thesis let's say today. How long after that does it take to receive a piece of paper saying something like "University of SUCH Master Degree in favor of SUCH"?

I know Spain, France, UK, USA are very different countries and all systems must have differences. Any country of the previous ones mentioned is good for me. It is a simple curiosity of mine.

Comment: USA on average, you get the PHYSICAL DEGREE CERT ~1 semester after you defend, turn in your thesis and have it approved by gradschool. The key here is `~`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the university you attend and how many credits they require for a master degree. In out university, 30 credits (10 courses) needed to complete a master degree. But finishing time depends on you. You can take all these courses in one year (spring, summer, fall) or do it in two years or even three. Its totally up to you.

The graduation document, I mean the degree, would be awarded the last day of your last semester. That would be your official "master" title date. The will mail the document to your home address. Plus you can also collect the document on graduation day at the end of spring semester. If you have graduated in Fall 2013, you can attend graduation day in May 2014 and get the degree with fancy clothing.

Comment: Thanks, I'm asking for the "title" the one in paper with signatures, etc. I mean the student defend their thesis. After that how long it takes to receive a paper saying something like "University of SUCH Master Title in favor of SUCH". My question was not properly asked. I will edit it.

Comment: @ElMarce I have added the answer

Comment: Ah... graduation document, thanks I'm spanish speaking and the word title is used for both significates. Thanks.

Comment: If this is a US-centric answer, I don't consider it complete. Some universities will hold graduation ceremonies after every semester or quarter. If everything is complete, you can either pick up the certificate at the ceremony or it will be mailed (I imagine within a few weeks).